# Getting an error while making NotesApp using kotlin in Android Studio. Error and code is listed below

Tags: android, kotlin

Error:(44, 52) None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
public constructor ComponentName(p0: Context!, p1: Class<*>!) defined in android.content.ComponentName
public constructor ComponentName(p0: Context!, p1: String!) defined in android.content.ComponentName
public constructor ComponentName(p0: Parcel!) defined in android.content.ComponentName
public constructor ComponentName(p0: String!, p1: String!) defined in android.content.ComponentName

And here is my respective code file where i am getting error

```
package com.ayush.startup

import android.app.SearchManager
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter
import android.widget.SearchView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.ayush.NotesApp.AddNotes
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.ticket.view.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{

    var listNotes=ArrayList<Note>()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //Add Dummy Data
        listNotes.add(Note(1,"Meet Mr White","Yo Mr white you got some meth huh? why dont sell it and make profits to earn some real bucks and spend it on booze"))
        listNotes.add(Note(2,"Meet Heisenberg","Yo Mr white you got some meth huh? why dont sell it and make profits to earn some real bucks and spend it on booze"))
        listNotes.add(Note(3,"Meet ASAC Shrader","Yo Mr white you got some meth huh? why dont sell it and make profits to earn some real bucks and spend it on booze"))

        var myNotesAdapter=MyNotesAdapter(listNotes)
        lvNotes.adapter=myNotesAdapter
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean
    {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu)
        val sv=menu!!.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search).actionView as SearchView
        val sm=getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE) as SearchManager
        sv.setSearchableInfo(sm.getSearchableInfo(ComponentName()))
        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener
        {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean
            {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,query,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                //TODO: Search database
                return false
            }
            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean
            {
                return false
            }
        })
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean
    {
        if(item!=null)
        {
        when(item.itemId)
            {
            R.id.addNote ->
                {
                    //got to add page
                    var intent=Intent(this,AddNotes::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }

            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    inner class MyNotesAdapter:BaseAdapter
    {
        var listNotesAdapter=ArrayList<Note>()
        constructor(listNotesAdapter:ArrayList<Note>):super()
        {
            this.listNotesAdapter=listNotesAdapter
        }

        override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {
            var myView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ticket,null)
            var myNote=listNotesAdapter[p0]
            myView.tvTitle.text=myNote.noteName
            myView.tvDes.text=myNote.noteDes
            return myView

        }

        override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
            return listNotesAdapter[p0]
        }

        override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
            return p0.toLong()
        }
override fun getCount(): Int {
            return listNotesAdapter.size
            //this method will be called first and count how many elements are there and then run getView that no of times
}}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because you can't create a `ComponentName` instance with the code `ComponentName()` - it doesn't have a constructor that takes no parameters. While it has some other constructors (see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html)), you probably want the `ComponentName` of the current `Activity` you're in, which you can get by calling its [`getComponentName()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getComponentName()) method, or, since you're writing Kotlin code, accessing its `componentName` property:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        ...
        sv.setSearchableInfo(sm.getSearchableInfo(componentName))
        ...
     }

}
```